# Awesome_Notifications - Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter

I am using this [flutter library](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) to handle notifications. In the `initState()` in my `HomeView` I initialize this listener:

```
_notificationsActionStreamSubscription = AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
  print("user tapped on notification " + receivedNotification.id.toString());
});
```

Later when someone logs in or signs out of my app I call these lines:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeView()));
```

This let's the `initState()` of my `HomeView` be called again which results in the error:

```
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

That is why I did this before calling the two Navigator lines from above, but without success:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createdSink.close();
_notificationsActionStreamSubscription.cancel();
```

What am I doing wrong? I cancel the streamsubscription so why do I still get this error message?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Try _notificationsActionStreamSubscription.close();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, the listeners should be a top-level function and implemented in the main.dart file.
You should basically move all the listeners to a different function or class and then call it in the main function

```
void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  notificationInit();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: YourApp()));
}

void notificationInit() async {
  await AwesomeNotifications.initialize(...);
  _notificationsActionStreamSubscription = ...;
  _notificationsCreatedStreamSubscription = ...;
  _notificationsDisplayedStreamSubscription = ...;
  _notificationsDismissedStreamSubscription = ...;
}
```

Comment: Hi, beckzile.  I have almost exactly the same problem and I follow your instruction.  However, I have the following red underline error at the 'context' in 'of(context)'.showSnackBar.....''.   Pls help.... Thank a lot.

~~~

  AwesomeNotifications().createdStream.listen((notification) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        'Notification Created on ${notification.channelKey}',
      ),
    ));
  });

~~~

Comment: It's probably because you don't have access to any BuildContext in the function. You could create a new global key for the home page and access the context inside your createdStream listener. 
Assuming you have a stateful widget for the home page, you should first add this line outside of it `final HomeKey = new GlobalKey<_MyHomePageState>();`. And then inside the createdStream listener add this line `BuildContext context = HomeKey.currentContext;`. Now the error should be gone but I am not sure if this would work so let me know

Comment: Of course, you cannot grab context from any page. Take only from ones that have been initialised. In this case, it is assumed that MyHomePage is the `home` of the MaterialApp widget

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is not caused by `_notificationsActionStreamSubscription`.

If you read carefully it says

> Stream has already been listened to

That means that probably `AwesomeNotifications().actionStream` can only handle one listener at a time.

`_notificationsActionStreamSubscription.cancel()` doesn't seem to work, it is possible that `AwesomeNotifications().actionStream` doesn't know that the stream listener has been closed.

Every time the page get pushed, it is rebuilt, and `AwesomeNotifications()` throw an error becouse it thinks that you are attacching a second listener.

So I came with this solution: **Move the `notificationsActionStreamSubscription` to a widget which is parent to `HomeView`.**
Create the instance right there in the parent, and then attach it to the actionStream.
Every time you call `Navigator.pushReplacement` **send it as a parameter**.

**HomeView**: (I made it a statefullwidget)

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {

  final StreamSubscription<ReceivedAction> notificationsActionStreamSubscription;
  const HomeView({Key key, @required this.notificationsActionStreamSubscription}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  //You can access with widget.notificationsActionStreamSubscription
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('HomeView '),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

In your parent widget (I suppose it is a statefull widget):

```
  StreamSubscription<ReceivedAction> notificationsActionStreamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notificationsActionStreamSubscription =
        AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
      print(
          "user tapped on notification " + receivedNotification.id.toString());
    });
  }
```

And every time you push the HomeView:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeView(notificationsActionStreamSubscription:
                    notificationsActionStreamSubscription)));
```

By doing so, `notificationsActionStreamSubscription` will not be rebuilt and attached to `AwesomeNotifications().actionStream` every time you push the `HomeView`.

Comment: How do I give the `notificationsActionStreamSubscription` as a parameter when pushing HomeView? Where does it come from?

Comment: Since I don't know your complete app structure I can't tell you exactly.
In my case (I tryed to replicate your code) I was pushing the HomeView from another widget wich was called Root and  was defined inside the main.
I had defined notificationsActionStreamSubscription in that widget.

Answer (score 0):

Move the listeners to the initState method of the class. Suppose you were listening from the build method of the material app widget.

**Instead of** :

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Listener
   AwesomeNotifications().actionStream().listen((event) {});
  //
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
```

**Do this:**

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override 
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   AwesomeNotifications().actionStream().listen((event) {});
   }

   
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
```